# Long time of "Request Sent" in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, networking, time, request, timing

Our clients has issue that value of "Request sent" is 2.51 sec.

[image]

The google [says](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/long-time-spent-issuing-the-network-request-on-file-upload-2), that "Request sent" is:

> Time spent issuing the network request. Typically a fraction of a millisecond.

What may be reason of such long request sending?

Comment: Please aadd more details, which networks are active? wifi and eth both or just one? also this happens only for your site or other sites also on same chrome? which os and version?

Comment: Thanks, I have requested information.

Comment: chrome://net-export/ should have much more detailed information, with bytes processed. You should request for that as well. There's not much I can think of that would account for such a delay.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to see the details in the picture.
Possible reasons:

1. Your clients have a slow connection, or someone is abusing their bandwidth.
2. The files they are trying to access are very large.
3. The server has slow upload speed.
4. GetDocuments is trying to download many documents.

   - Option A: multiprocess the downloads.
   - If you don't have to show all the documents at once, download them asynchronously and show what you have when you have it.